# How do I make multiple slideshows in the same html document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm using the w3schools example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp, but when I try to add a second slideshow it won't appear until I move through the first one. I.E only one of the slideshows are open at a time. How can I have multiple slideshows (minimum 4) visible and usable at the same time?

Comment: Are you using different CSS `class` name for 2nd, 3rd and 4th sildeshow?

Comment: I'm now using the example provided by W. Scott in the answer below and I wonder if you know how to use CSS to set the position of the different slides separate of each other. I'm planning on putting each slideshow underneath the other on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assign an id to each slide container and provide that to all of the slideshow functions. In addition, use that same object to track the current slideshow index.

```js
var slideshow1 = document.getElementById("slideshow1");
slideshow1.currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideshow1.currentSlideIndex, slideshow1);

var slideshow2 = document.getElementById("slideshow2");
slideshow2.currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideshow2.currentSlideIndex, slideshow2);


function plusSlides(n, slideshow) {
  showSlides(slideshow.currentSlideIndex += n, slideshow);
}

function currentSlide(n, slideshow) {
  showSlides(slideshow.currentSlideIndex = n, slideshow);
}

function showSlides(n, slideshow) {
  


  var i;
  var slides = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,slideshow1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, slideshow1)">&#10095;</a>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow1)"></span> 
</div>
</div>
<br>





<div id="slideshow2" class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, this.parentNode)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, this.parentNode)">&#10095;</a>


<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow2)"></span> 
</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: This works, but I want to set the location of the slideshows using CSS, how do I do that?

Comment: Please make my solution as answer. Also, you can style each slideshow independent of each other using 
    #slideshow1 { //ENTER STYLE HERE } or #slideshow2 { //ENTER STYLE HERE } in your stylesheet.