# Why do the slideshows not work (anymore)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

As you can see in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380644/how-to-make-an-image-fit-into-a-simple-auto-playing-slideshow/65381958?noredirect=1#comment115620880_65381958), I've managed to get a slideshow working.

I wanted to put on more slideshows, unfortunately they don't work although I think I've used the same code/design.
And the original slideshow is also not working anymore :(. I got stationary slide shows now.

Can anybody see what I should do in order to get all slideshows working again?

Here's the code:

**HTML**
`

```
        <!-- Featured ad 1 -->
        <div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd1">
            <div>
                <img src="Img4.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="Img5.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
              <div>
                 <img src="Img6.jpg"  height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
         </div>

        <!-- Featured ad 2 -->
        <div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd2">
            <div>
                <img src="Img7.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="Img8.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
              <div>
                 <img src="Img9.jpg"  height="150px" width="75px">
              </div>
         </div>

        <!-- Featured ad 3 -->
        <div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd3">
            <div>
              <img src="Img10.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="Img11.jpg" height="150px" width="75px">
            </div>
            <div>
               <img src="Img12.jpg"  height="150px" width="75px">
            </div>
         </div>`
```

**CSS**

```
/* General settings */
body {
    font-family: helvetica;
}

* {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }

/* Starring ads */
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }

#SlideshowStarringAds {
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
  
#SlideshowStarringAds {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
  
#SlideshowStarringAds > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Featured ad 1 */
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }

#SlideshowFeaturedAd1 {
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd1 {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd1 > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Featured ad 2 */
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }

#SlideshowFeaturedAd2 {
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    right: 39%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd2 {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd2 > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Featured ad 3 */
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  }

#SlideshowFeaturedAd3 {
    margin: 80px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: 25%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd3 {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
}
  
#SlideshowFeaturedAd3 > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

**Javascript in HTML head**

```
        <!-- Code Javascript belonging to starring ads -->
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);
        });
        </script>
        <!-- End of Java script -->
```

**Javascript file**
Downloadable from [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21APzyaGWYsWklZic&cid=17DE96AB18076E69&id=17DE96AB18076E69%215684&parId=17DE96AB18076E69%215683&o=OneUp)

Comment: Two points. 1) Please provide the link to your previous question at the start of the question. 2) Please provide the link to your Javascript file, probably a github link.

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380644/how-to-make-an-image-fit-into-a-simple-auto-playing-slideshow/65381958?noredirect=1#comment115620880_65381958.

2) It's on onedrive now publicly shared: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmluBxirlt4XrDT88mhlmLFpJWYn?e=srOjq7

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your javascript, you can add:

```js
var slideshow1 = document.getElementById("SlideshowFeaturedAd1");
slideshow1.currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideshow1.currentSlideIndex, slideshow1);

var slideshow2 = document.getElementById("SlideshowFeaturedAd2");
slideshow2.currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideshow2.currentSlideIndex, slideshow2);

var slideshow2 = document.getElementById("SlideshowFeaturedAd3");
slideshow2.currentSlideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideshow2.currentSlideIndex, slideshow2);

function plusSlides(n, slideshow) {
  showSlides(slideshow.currentSlideIndex += n, slideshow);
}

function currentSlide(n, slideshow) {
  showSlides(slideshow.currentSlideIndex = n, slideshow);
}

function showSlides(n, slideshow) {
  var i;
  var slides = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Then in your CSS, you can add:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Finally in your HTML, you can add:

```html
<!-- Featured ad 1 -->
<div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd1">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img4.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img5.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img6.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,slideshow1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, slideshow1)">&#10095;</a>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow1)"></span> 
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Featured ad 2 -->
<div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd2">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img7.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img8.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img9.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,slideshow1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, slideshow1)">&#10095;</a>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow1)"></span> 
   </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Featured ad 3 -->
<div id="SlideshowFeaturedAd3">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img10.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img11.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="Img12.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 75px;">
      <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,slideshow1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, slideshow1)">&#10095;</a>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow1)"></span> 
   </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Also, this question is similar to:

[How do I make multiple slideshows in the same html document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299759/how-do-i-make-multiple-slideshows-in-the-same-html-document/43300869)

Since, that question has an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and effort. I think I can see you made 3 slideshows with buttons. That's an improvement.

Still the big container with slideshow is stationary. It changed automatically before.

The 3 smaller slideshows with buttons don't display the other images automatically and also not when I press next or back button.

I've just added all the code you mentioned. Do I also need to change the javascriptfile itself? Cause I only changed the javascriptcode in the HTML header.

Sorry to be so extensive. I'm really new to this.